# send email from node.js app using nodemailer

Tags: node.js, sendmail, nodemailer

From my ubuntu (10.04) box, I have no problem send email with:

```
echo "hello" | mail -s 'test email' my_gmail_nickname@gmail.com
```

When I try to send an email from a node.js app running on the same machine, it does not work.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
nodemailer.SMTP = {
  host: 'localhost'
}
nodemailer.send_mail(
{
    sender: 'me@example.com',
    to:'my_gmail_nickname@gmail.com',
    subject:'Hello!',
    html: 'test',
    body:'test'
},
function(error, success){
    console.log(error);
    console.log(success);
    console.log('Message ' + success ? 'sent' : 'failed');
});
```

I have the error message:

```
me@luc:~/gridteams/services/gpshop$ cat nohup.out 
{ stack: [Getter/Setter],
  arguments: undefined,
  type: undefined,
  message: 'ECONNREFUSED, Connection refused',
  errno: 111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }
null
sent
```

I see the connection refused but do not understand why I get this error. What do you think is the missing piece ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your problem is like this:

The commandline program *mail* uses a binary called */usr/sbin/sendmail* for sending mail. sendmail is a commandline programm which will try to deliver the mail. It uses a local connection to the mail infrastructure.

The node nodemailer will try to connect to a SMTP server on the host *localhost* on TCP port 25 which doesn't exist. Just try to get a connection using the telnet program for verification.

Here is a server running:

```
$ telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 xxxx.de ESMTP Postfix
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

here is no server running:

```
$ telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

If you get the second, you have a problem with your SMTP which is not started/enabled listening on port 25 - which is the default (for security reasons). You need to configure it first.

Or - according to the nodemail documentation you can use the sendmail binary as well:

> ```
> 'sendmail' alternative
>
> Alternatively if you don't want to use SMTP but the sendmail
> ```
>
> command then set property sendmail to true (or as the path to sendmail
>   if the command is not in default path).
>
> ```
> nodemailer.sendmail = true;
>
> or
>
> nodemailer.sendmail = '/path/to/sendmail';
>
> If sendmail is set, then SMTP options are discarded.
> ```

Comment: You'r right, I got the second message "telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused". In fact, I though sendmail was using the SMTP server running on the localhost as well.

Comment: I installed postfix, and after a little bit of struggle it works fine :). Thanks a lot.